# How can I hide the share or sign in button in Google Docs editor?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

How can I hide or disable the sign in button on this [page](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18ilggkYRgeC4cIM_Fb_EVO5HBlvnFfpbTOq7K-t1OBw/edit?usp=drivesdk) through Javascript after loading that page in Iframe?

Are there any APIs that I can use to do that or any other way to disable or hide that button?

Note: I am using Google Drive API V2.

Answer (score 0):

Since that editor is Google-managed, I don't think we can edit what's displayed other than overriding the CSS

I tried it out, if you can manage to specify these styles I believe you can hide them

```
#docs-titlebar-share-client-button:{display:none;}
#gb_70:{display:none;}
```

I'd still suggest you use the [Google Drive Realtime API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/overview) as it gives you more control on what/how you want to display the document. However, you'll need to re-implement most (if not, all) of the features on the document editor.